# CSS: change font-size based on how many lines text inside an element spans/wraps with the initial font-size

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

If the text in my div would be one line only (with the current set font-size), then I want it to stay the currently set font-size (e.g. the font size of the tailwindcss class text-5xl).

If the text in my div would wrap once, i.e. be two lines, then I would like it to be a bit smaller (e.g. the font size of the tailwindcss class text-4xl)

If the text in my div would wrap twice, i.e. be two lines, then I would like it to be a bit smaller (e.g. the font size of the tailwindcss class text-3xl)

...and so on

Seems like this is a pretty common use case of dynamic text font-size generation, which is why I am wondering why there is no such question with fitting solutions.

Preferably I would like to do this only with CSS since counting lines with javascript seems like an unclean-code solution since font(size,height,weight) might change & additionaly I think there would be flickering after the rendering finished since the javascript runs after the first rendering finishes.

I am wondering why there is no such CSS concept like for example media queries of doing sth based on the number of lines an element wraps with the intitial styles. Or what would also maybe work as a workaround is media queries based on the initial size/width of an element. (with initial I mean the styles that were applied outside of the media query)

If there is really no such solution then I would happily like to have this confirmed & also like to have other answers which provide the currently cleanest solution to problems like this.

Comment: No there is no such property although "container queries" might get you close. Unfortunately, this is not an easy solution since the width of the element will depend on the size of the font but then the font size will depend on the width of the element... a circular sizing problem and browsers don't like those.

Comment: CSS has no property to detect overflow or wrapping so JS is your only option here.